# Creating a dictionary of categoricals in SQL and aggregating them in Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, presto

I have a rather "cross platformed" question. I hope it is not too general.

One of my tables, say `customers`, consists of my customer id's and their associated demographic information. Another table, say `transaction`, contains all purchases from the customers in the respective shops.
I am interested in analyzing basket compositions together with demographics in python. Hence, I would like to have the shops as columns and the sum for the given customers at the shops in my dataframe

For clarity,

```
 select *
 from customer
 where id=1 or id=2
```

gives me

```
 id     age      gender
 1      35       MALE
 2      57       FEMALE
```

and

```
 select *
 from transaction
 where id=1 or id=2
```

gives me

```
 customer_id     shop     amount
 1               2        250
 1               2        500
 2               3        100
 2               7        200
 2               11       125
```

Which should end up in a (preferably) Pandas dataframe as

```
 id     age      gender      shop_2     shop_3     shop_7   shop_11
 1      35       MALE        750        0          0        0   
 2      57       FEMALE      0          100        200      125
```

Such that the last columns is the aggregated baskets of the customers.

I have tried to create a python dictionary of the purchases and amounts for each customer in SQL in the following way:

```
 select customer_id, array_agg(concat(cast(shop as varchar), ' : ', cast(amount as varchar))) as basket
 from transaction
 group by customer_id
```

Resulting in

```
 id    basket
 1     ['2 : 250', '2 : 500']
 2     ['3 : 100', '7 : 200', '11 : 125']
```

which could easily be joined on the customer table.

However, this solution is not optimal due to the fact that it is strings and not integers inside the []. Hence, it involves a lot of manipulation and looping in python to get it on the format I want.

Is there any way where I can aggregate the purchases in SQL making it easier for python to read and aggregate into columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to do the aggregation in pandas using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) on the second dataframe and then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with the first:

```
df2 = df2.pivot_table(columns='shop', values='amount', index='customer_id', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0.0).reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='id', right_on='customer_id')
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
id  age  gender   2   3   7  11
 1   35    MALE 750   0   0   0
 2   57  FEMALE   0 100 200 125
```